# "Image set" or "Images set"?

Tags: grammar, technical, descriptive-grammar

Should it be "image set" or "images set"? What about "datum set" and "data set"?

Or does it just depend on the context? For the above, I would use "image set" and "data set". I am trying to decide whether I should use "stimulus set" or "stimuli set".

Also, I know that "set" is a collective noun, but what is "image"? An adjective?

Comment: The rule of thumb is to use whatever you call a single element of the set. *Data* is an odd one - it is now treated as a non-count noun in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generally use the singular, although "data set" has become accepted as normal.

Consider: car collection vs cars collection; tool kit (or toolkit) vs tools kit; stock portfolio vs stocks portfolio.